# Ошибка C2280 при сборке с MSVC и пакетом параметров

Tags: c++, c++17

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <deque>

template<class T>
struct Caller;

template<class R, class... Args>
struct Caller<R(Args...)>
{
    using PackagedTask = std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>;
    using InternalTask = std::packaged_task<void(void)>;
     
    void enque(PackagedTask&& task, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto fnc = [](auto&& task, auto&&... args) -> void
        { if (task.valid()) task(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };

        auto bnd = std::bind(std::move(fnc),
            std::forward<PackagedTask>(task),
            std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        m_tasks.emplace_back(std::move(bnd));
    }
    
    void run()
    {
        if (!m_tasks.empty())
        {
            auto& task = m_tasks.front();
            if (task.valid()) task();
            m_tasks.pop_front();
        }
    }
    
    std::deque<InternalTask> m_tasks;
};

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int(int)> task
    {
        [](auto a)
        {
            std::cout << "tra-ta-ta: " << a << std::endl;
            return 5;
        }
    };
    
    Caller<int(int)> c;
    c.enque(std::move(task), 5);
    c.run();
}
```

С компилятором GCC собирается без ошибок, MSVC же выдаёт C2280.
Прошу помощи разобраться, что именно ему не нравится и как это можно исправить?

***UPD** Судя по всему, проблема связана с [этим](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108672/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta.html). И решения нет.

Comment: Ну сделайте очередь (умных) указателей на `packaged_task`, будет работать под всеми компиляторами.

Comment: @VladD, но там не только packaged_task, но и связанная с ним пачка аргументов для вызова. Их тогда надо тоже как-то "упаковать". А как только я пытаюсь использовать std::bind - труба.

Comment: Возился, смотрел,.. Похоже несоотвествие типа функций у вас. `std::deque<InternalTask> m_tasks; InternalTask=void(void)` А вы пихаете туда `[](auto&& task, auto&&... args) -> void`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Пихают туда `bnd` а это сбайнденная функция (со связанными аргументами) типа `void(void)`, пихают не `fnc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно замечено [по ссылке](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108672/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta.html), это баг MSVC компилятора, который пофиксили и запланировали исправить на следующем major релизе.

Как было уже сказано, одно из возможных решений, чтобы обойти это ограничение - это обернуть `std::packaged_task` в умный указатель (через `std::make_shared`). Если среди остальных параметров (args) бывают также `std::packaged_task` объекты, то их тоже надо будет обернуть.

Код ниже работает и под Windows (MSVC) и под Linux (CLang/G++). Только обязательно условие под Linux это добавление опции `-pthread`, без неё std::packaged_task бросает исключение std::system_error `"Unknown error -1"`.

Рабочий код ниже (оборачивает и task и args):

[Попробовать на онлайн Windows MSVC!](https://rextester.com/WEYC49656)

[Попробовать на онлайн Linux G++/CLang!](https://godbolt.org/z/M4h8Eh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
struct Caller;

template<class R, class... Args>
struct Caller<R(Args...)>
{
    using PackagedTask = std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>;
    using InternalTask = std::packaged_task<void(void)>;
     
    void enque(PackagedTask&& task, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto fnc = [](auto&& task, auto&&... args) -> void
        { if (task->valid()) (*task)(std::forward<Args>(*args)...); };

        auto bnd = std::bind(std::move(fnc),
            std::make_shared<PackagedTask>(std::forward<PackagedTask>(task)),
            std::make_shared<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
            
        m_tasks.emplace_back(std::move(bnd));
    }
    
    void run()
    {
        if (!m_tasks.empty())
        {
            auto& task = m_tasks.front();
            if (task.valid()) task();
            m_tasks.pop_front();
        }
    }
    
    std::deque<InternalTask> m_tasks;
};

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int(int)> task
    {
        [](auto a)
        {
            std::cout << "tra-ta-ta: " << a << std::endl;
            return 5;
        }
    };
    
    Caller<int(int)> c;
    c.enque(std::move(task), 5);
    c.run();
}
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось, не помогает, проверил в `g++ 10.2`. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7j37sq

Comment: @AlexGlebe Задача автора была добиться компиляции и работы под MSVC, а не под GCC. Под MSVC [вот смотрите работает](https://rextester.com/WEYC49656). Для GCC у автора по его словам уже всё итак работало. Тем более задача стояла добиться компилируемости, а это у вас ошибка рантайма, исключение при исполнении, я конечно посмотрю что за ошибка, может легко исправляется.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Только что проверил под Windows на 3х компиляторах у себя дома MSVC/G++/CLang. Все три верно отработали. Видимо что то именно для Linux специфичное, сервера GodBolt на линуксе. Попробую домашний линукс ещё.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Разобрался, под линуксом нужно добавить либу многопоточности через `-pthread` опцию, вот [рабочий вариант](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8b7T8z), только добавил опцию.

Comment: маладец, программыстом будеш

Comment: @Arty, не знал, что пачку аргументов можно вот так вот просто в указатель вставить. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexis031182 На самом деле синтаксис `std::make_shared<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args))...` не вставляет в указатель. Этот синтаксис создаёт из пачки аргументов пачку указателей, т.е. это не один указатель, а результатом является пачка из указателей разного типа. В общем случае синтаксис `f(args)...` означает 1) вызвать f для каждого аргумента (по одному) из пачки args 2) результаты возврата f (возможно разных типов) соединить в результирующую пачку из разных типов.

Comment: @Arty, понял, спасибо за уточнение.